# Cant redirect to a Facebook canvas page

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I am trying to keep my iframe based facebook canvas app within the Facebook chrome, however, after I cannot redirect to my canvas app as follows

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/my_fb_app

I can redirect if the redirect_uri is the canvas host server ... http://myserver.com. This does not work as it takes me out of the facebook context.

All the docs indicate that you can use your canvas page URL.

I have configured my app to be both an "App on Facebook" and a "Page Tab".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable *App on Facebook* with both of your URLs for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to use
http://apps.facebook.com/your_namespace

You can set the namespace in the facebook-settings.